# Send response to the website indicating a successful login after the user clicks the "start" button using the Telegram Bot API

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

How can I send a response to the website indicating a successful login after the user clicks the "start" button using the Telegram Bot API and the provided code snippet?

Explanation:

I have implemented a Telegram bot using the Telegram Bot API, and I'm using the provided code snippet to handle user logins. When a user clicks the "start" button after using the t.me link, the code checks the session ID and retrieves the corresponding session data. If the session data is found, the user's information is updated, and a success message is sent to the Telegram chat. However, I would like to know how I can send a response back to the website that initiated the login process, indicating that the login was successful.

Thank you for your assistance.

```
app.get("/generate-session", (req, res) => {
    const sessionId = req.sessionID;

    req.session.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error saving session:", err);
            return res
                .status(500)
                .json({ success: false, error: "Failed to save session" });
        }

        res.cookie("sessionId", req.sessionID, {
            httpOnly: false,
            secure: true,
            sameSite: "None",
        });

        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, sessionId });
    });
});
```

```
bot.onText(/\/start (.+)/, async (msg, match) => {
    const { chat, from } = msg;
    const chatId = chat.id;
    const sessionId = match[1];

    const sessionData = await getSessionData(sessionId);

    if (sessionData) {
        const { id, first_name, last_name, username } = from;

        const newSessionData = await mongoose.connection
            .collection("sessions")
            .updateOne(
                { _id: sessionId },
                { $set: { chatId: id, username, first_name, last_name } }
            );

        const responseMessage = `Welcome, ${username}! You are now logged in.`;
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, responseMessage);
    } else {
        const responseMessage = "Invalid session ID. Please log in again.";
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, responseMessage);
    }
});
```